# Difference between l-value ref-qualified member function and unqualified member function?

Tags: c++, c++11, overload-resolution, ref-qualifier

Is there a difference between l-value ref-qualified member functions and unqualified member functions? If so, what is it?

I.e., are these two ways of declaring `func()` different?

```
class Foo
{
  void func();
  void func() &;
};
```

I don't mean "are they different enough to permit overload resolution," because obviously the above class does not compile when both versions of `func()` are present. I mean, how and why does the compiler behave differently when `&` is included versus when it isn't?

There is at least one difference, which is that ref-qualified functions (of either l-value or r-value type) cannot be overloaded with non-ref-qualified functions. From the [current standard draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/bc41360f3b9429145369d9b8c38e99b0a175846f/source/overloading.tex):

> Member function declarations with the same name and the same
>   parameter-type-list as well as member function template
>   declarations with the same name, the same parameter-type-list, and
>   the same template parameter lists cannot be overloaded if any of them, but not
>   all, have a ref-qualifier.

...but if this is the only difference, why the restriction? I.e., why can't `foo()&&` be treated as a valid override of (unqualified) `foo()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are different.

```
Foo foo;
std::move(foo).func();
```

will call `func()` but not `func()&`.

Similarly:

```
Foo make_foo() { return {}; }
make_foo().func();
```

will only work on the `void func()` signature, not the `void func()&` signature.

`void func()&` means that it only is a valid call on lvalues, not rvalues.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Is there any context in which `void func()&` is *less* restrictive? (I wouldn't expect so, but...) And what exactly is `return {};`? Does it just default-initialize a value of whatever the return-type is? I haven't seen that before.

Comment: @KyleStrand I am uncertain what you mean, but probably not.  `return {};` is directly constructing the return value with zero arguments.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant--not default-initialize.

Comment: @KyleStrand since C++11 a brace-enclosed list can be implicitly converted to a temporary

Comment: One good place to use lvalue ref is in the assignment operator: `T &operator=(T t) &` , this will prevent `bar() = 5;` for example, where `bar()` returns by value

Comment: @MattMcNabb in fact, most "my primary or only purpose is to mutate the object with no side effects" should be `&` qualified.  Methods that return references to internal guts should have both `&` and `&&` with `&&` returning either a moved-copy, or a `&&` reference.

Comment: @Yakk Yep, overloading a method to get a copy of some internal guts was exactly how I ran into this.